# Rails proper way to display fields from another model in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model

I have two models, one named Order and the other named Member.
In my Order model I have:

```
has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :members
```

and in my Member model I have:

```
belongs_to :order
```

My members database has a name field thats a string. Now my question is, how do I display that field from my members database in my orders view. Would I use a fields_for tag? Basically what I want is an Order form, but also on the same page to fill out information about the Members for your order and it to save that information to the members database instead of in the orders database.

For example something like this:

```
Your name: textfield
Member 1 name: textfield
Member 2 name: textfield
```

How would i do this? is it possible to create more than one name field for the members without having to copy and paste it multiple times such as with a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `fields_for`, for this particular scenario.

There are several Railscasts that make use of `fields_for`, but this is one of the later ones.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your needs should be pretty well met by [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

Comment: do you know how I could accomplish this without cocoon?

Comment: So you want to accomplish the same thing that cocoon accomplishes (dynamic nested forms) without using cocoon? I'm not sure why you'd take that route, but looking at the cocoon source code would be a good way to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just new to rails and I want to learn how everything works. I don't want to have to rely on a gem

Comment: Part of being a Rails programmer *is* knowing that you have a wealth of gems in your toolbox.  Don't avoid them, embrace them!

Comment: @Jake d11wtq is right, gems like cocoon are one of the biggest advantages of using Rails. Looking through their source code is a great way to learn how things work, but you'll save yourself a lot of time and frustration if you don't re-implement everything yourself. Remember, Rails itself is a gem.